# Connect to a mySQL database in java using SSL connection

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, ssl

Please know that I am quite new at databases. I was able to properly install mySQL and install the java connector driver. But whenever I run a program in eclipse and try to retrieve info from a database I created I get the following message: "SSL Connection required, but not supported by server". Here the code I want to run with a secure SSL connection:

`public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String username = "";
    String password = "";
    String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo" 
                    + "?verifyServerCertificate=false"
                    + "&useSSL=false"
                    + "&requireSSL=false";


    try{
        // 1. Get a connection to database

        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username,    password);

        // 2. Create a statement

        Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

        // 3. Execute SQL query

        ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("select name from movies");

        // 4. Process the result set

        while(myRs.next()){
            System.out.println(myRs.getString("name") );
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exc){
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }`
```

Answer (score 4):

To enable SSL connections, your MySQL distribution must be built with SSL support, as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/building-with-ssl-support.html). In addition, the proper [SSL-related options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ssl-options.html) must be used to specify the appropriate certificate and key files.

To check SSL support you can use this command:

```
mysqld --ssl --help
```

To communicate with a MySQL database by using SSL and JDBC you should pass some connection propery in the JDBC URL:

```
String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo" 
    + "?verifyServerCertificate=true" 
    + "&useSSL=true"
    + "&requireSSL=true";
```

Comment: Bypassing certificate verification means you might as well not be using SSL at all.

Comment: @o11c I disagree. The trafic will still be SSL encrypted.

Comment: @frankhommers yes, but encrypted using the attacker's choice of certificate, not the server's real certificate.

Comment: @o11c when not attacked, using ssl will encrypt. Not using it will make all your queries and results sniffable.